# INSERT multiple data in MySQL using Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I just want to insert multiple data in my database using vuex.

As of now it say: COLUMN DOESN'T MATCH VALUE COUNT AT ROW 1 even if I only inserted two data in my database.

[image]

Below is my code in store.js that tries to insert data into database.

```
  async addArticle({ commit }, name, address) {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:9001/article/add', {
        name: name, address: address
    });
    commit('ADD_ARTICLE', response.data)
}
```

and here is my insert.vue

```
<template>
  <section>
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-card raised>
        <v-card-title
          class="display-2 font-weight-bold"
          style="border-bottom: green 3px solid"
        >NEW ARTICLE</v-card-title>
      </v-card>
      <v-card raised style="margin-top:10px">
        <v-card-text class="headline font-weight-black">
          <v-layout>
            <v-row align-content="center">
              <v-col>
                TITLE
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="title"
                  filled
                  placeholder="Provide a Title for the article"
                  prepend-icon="title"
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
              <v-col>
                SUBHEADER
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="subheader"
                  filled
                  placeholder="Provide a description for the article"
                  prepend-icon="description"
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-layout>
          <v-btn color="red white--text" style="margin:10px" @click="passToDB">SUBMIT</v-btn>
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-container>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
      subheader: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addArticle"]),
    passToDB() {
      this.addArticle({ name: this.title, address: this.subheader });

    }
  }
};
</script>
```

What is my mistake in my code? I'll appreciate for the help.

Comment: The SQL in the error suggests that there is a NULL added at the end of values making it try to insert three values to two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by creating an object and put the data into that object. After creating I pass it as an argument to **action addArticle** in my store.js

```
 passToDB() {
  let payload = {
    TITLE: this.title,
    SUBHEADER: this.subheader,
    CONTENT: this.content,
    CATEGORY: this.category
  };
  this.addArticle(payload);
```

here I received the payload coming from insert.vue file

```
 async addArticle({ commit }, payload) {
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:9001/article/add', payload);
    commit('ADD_ARTICLE', response.data)
}
```